# ColdFusion XML Document return type

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I've created a abstract `file parser` cfc. This, as it sounds, abstracts some common tasks  that are required when I read files from the file system.

One child of said component is for parsing XML Files and returns a coldfusion XML document. Now this all works perfectly, however, one thing I am unable to figure out is **how to explicitly define the return type of the xml document**, something I am keen to enforce.

The method responsible for returning the XML document is below:

```
public coldfusion.xml.XmlNodeList function parse(string filePath = "", boolean isCaseSensitive = false, string validator = "")
{
  super.parse(arguments.filePath);
  var data = getData();
  if (len(arguments.validator)) {
    setDocument(xmlParse(data, arguments.isCaseSensitive, arguments.validator));
  } else {
    setDocument(xmlParse(data, arguments.isCaseSensitive));
  }
  return getDocument();
}
```

You can see that the return type is `coldfusion.xml.XmlNodeList`. This I have managed to figure out by using the following client code.

```
<cfscript>

  factory = new Library.parser.Factory();
  parser  = factory.getParser("XmlFileParser");
  xmlDoc  = parser.parse("/var/www/development/Framework/test/testfile.xml");

  /** XMLDoc is now a coldfusion document object **/

  writeDump(xmlDoc);
  writeDump(getMetadata(xmlDoc).getName()); /** outputs coldfusion.xml.XmlNodeList **/

</cfscript>
```

This is incorrect, the error I get is:

`The value returned from the parse function is not of type coldfusion.xml.XmlNodeList.`

Am I missing something really simple? Should I care so much?

**EDIT:**

Added the getDocument method (which as you can see has a return type of "any")

```
public any function getDocument()
{
  return variables.document;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep.  As per [the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f5c.html), the return type you want for XML is... err... "XML".

Comment: +1 Ha ha, how embarrassing, of course I did look but must have missed it. In my defence I was convinced it was a component type of some sort.